# Bash memory leak disconnected me from SSH?

Tags: ssh, bash

Can someone explain to me what happened here?

I simply typed `cd /some/directory`, maybe I pressed tab for directory listing, when the following happened and I got disconnected from the server:

```
me@psrv1:/opt/data$ cd /opt/data/perl

malloc: ../bash/parse.y:6050: assertion botched
free: called with already freed block argument
last command: ls
Aborting...Connection to psrv1 closed.
```

Comment: This should never happen. Either the bash binary or a library is corrupt, or the hardware is having a problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Bash memory leak disconnected me from SSH?

Not memory leak, but `assertion`. You can imagine the process tree on the server:

```
sshd
 '--- bash
```

When process hits a place where is assertion, it usually means that some variable has some invalid value (that it should never have) and to prevent failures later, the process is aborted (ends).

The `sshd` server, who started your shell, is waiting only for the shell process to end to clean up your connection, which happened just in this moment and therefore closes connection for you.

That's all folks.